Multilingual SharePoint Framework (SPFx) - switching language
I'm adding multilingual support to an existing webpart.  Easy enough with the different locale string files and testing with the --locale pararmeter on gulp serve.
What I don't understand though is how the locale is picked up in production, I have a site, created in English.  I have tried:

Adding a translation for Spanish and publishing the new page - still English
Changing my uuser account default language to Spanish - web part still shows in English.

I was hoping the webpart would display differently based on the user or the page translation, not the site language?
Also, is it possible to change the locale of the webpart at runtime?  Potentially with a webpart prop or reading the user's preferred language?
I have tried settng the cultureInfo on the context to 'es-ES', pre-render (I know it's supposed to be read only!), which did nothing.
Any ideas? Thanks

I have the same problem and I didn`t see any OOTB way to solve it.
I solved it using the solution found at https://digitalworkplace365.wordpress.com/2021/04/13/spfx-react-localization-an-easy-alternative/
You must change the resources but the change is really simple (you can see it in the link). After that, the only change is to set the language
strings.setLanguage

I've added at my component the following code to set the language depends on the page translation:
protected override async onInit(): Promise<void> {
   getSP(this.context);
   this.pageLocale = await getPageLocale(this.context.pageContext.list?.id.toString() as string, this.context.pageContext.listItem?.id as number)
   strings.setLanguage(this.pageLocale || this.context.pageContext.web.languageName);
   return super.onInit();

}
And the code to get the page language:
export async function getPageLocale(sitePagesId: string, pageId: number, context?: WebPartContext): Promise<string | undefined> {
try {
    const _sp = getSP(context);
    const pageLocale = await _sp.web.lists.getById(sitePagesId).items.getById(pageId).select("OData__SPIsTranslation,OData__SPTranslationLanguage")();
    if (pageLocale && (pageLocale['OData__SPIsTranslation']) === true) {
        return pageLocale['OData__SPTranslationLanguage'] as string;
    }
}
catch (error) {
    if (error?.status === 400) {
        
        return undefined
    } else {
        throw (error);
    }
   
}

}
Be carefull, you must add the error 400 handler. If page has not translations the service returns 400 error

Oooo, interesting solution. Looks promising!!  Thanks for sharing
